# Is there a way to find out which exceptions is the Dart function throwing?

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase

Simply, I am working with SupabaseAPI:

```
Future<AuthResponse> signUp({
    String? email,
    String? phone,
    required String password,
    String? emailRedirectTo,
    Map<String, dynamic>? data,
    String? captchaToken,
  }) async {
    assert((email != null && phone == null) || (email == null && phone != null),
        'You must provide either an email or phone number');

    _removeSession();

    late final Map<String, dynamic> response;

    if (email != null) {
      final urlParams = <String, String>{};

      response = await _fetch.request(
        '$_url/signup',
        RequestMethodType.post,
        options: GotrueRequestOptions(
          headers: _headers,
          redirectTo: emailRedirectTo,
          body: {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'data': data,
            'gotrue_meta_security': {'captcha_token': captchaToken},
          },
          query: urlParams,
        ),
      );
    } else if (phone != null) {
      final body = {
        'phone': phone,
        'password': password,
        'data': data,
        'gotrue_meta_security': {'captcha_token': captchaToken},
      };
      final fetchOptions = GotrueRequestOptions(headers: _headers, body: body);
      response = await _fetch.request('$_url/signup', RequestMethodType.post,
          options: fetchOptions) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    } else {
      throw AuthException(
          'You must provide either an email or phone number and a password');
    }

    final authResponse = AuthResponse.fromJson(response);

    final session = authResponse.session;
    if (session != null) {
      _saveSession(session);
      _notifyAllSubscribers(AuthChangeEvent.signedIn);
    }

    return authResponse;
  }
```

This function can throw an exception, but in the function declaration it is not specified, so I have to look for the possible exception manually in order to catch the specific exception in the try/catch block. This is very frustrating, since this function can call another function that throws some other exception...

Comment: No, there is no way.  Exceptions that are expected as part of the interface should be documented.  If they're not, complain to the API author.

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/984

Comment: This is a pain point that is addressed, and Supabase will add proper error codes for auth exceptions in the future. https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/issues/842

Comment: why return exceptions at all, why not to use Either<Left, RIght>??

Comment: @dshukertjr forgot to tag you, sorry

Comment: @JanCahlík With `<Left, Right>` do you mean to return the values in `{ data, error }` format similar to js client library? We don't do that, because it's just not a common design patterns in Dart.